# How to use Interface-Bridging-Header.h in macos Sonoma

Tags: objective-c, bridging-header, xcode15, macos-sonoma

I have two rather old app that use Objectiv-C-code, integrated with an Interface-Bridging-Header file.
One runs well on Sonoma, but the other has an NSViewViewController class using IBOutlets and IBActions in the Objective-C-Part. That run well in macos Monterey with Xcode 14. But now with Sonoma and Xcode15, the IBOutlets and the corresponding IBActions are not connected any more:
For the IBOutlets, the error is:

```
Failed to connect (CNC_BlockKonfigurierenTaste) outlet from (NSViewController) to (NSButton): missing setter or instance variable
```

and the error for the IBAction is

```
Could not connect action. Target class 'NSViewController' does not respond to '-reportBlockkonfigurieren:'
```

The IBOutlet CNC_BlockKonfigurierenTaste and the IBAction function reportBlockkonfigurieren are declared in the Objective-C header file and implemented in the corresponding c file.

The IBOutlets defined in the Objectiv-C file also do not respond to mouseclicks.

The viewcontroller is

```
class rViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate
```

It has a member AVR which is instantiated inas

```
var AVR = rAVRview()
```

The project is a CNC-Hotwire-cutting app, started in 2014 in pure Objectiv-C and revised for every new version of Xcode. It run well until macos Monterey. The objective-C files are about 25'000 lines, making translating to swift a big job.

My question:
Is connecting IBOutlets and IBActions from Objective-C no more supported in Xcode15?

Comment: `-reportBlockkonfigurieren:` is an action, not an outlet. What is the class of the view controller in IB? How is the view controller instantiated? How old is the Xcode project?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post corresponding to your questions.

Comment: Are the outlet and action connected in a xib or storyboard? How is the `rViewController` instantiated?